# KSoap2 & Android - Impossible authentication (Username + Password)

Tags: android, authentication, soap, https, ksoap2

I am actually working on an Android app that must consume a Soap WebService, using the KSoap2 library...
By the past, I didn't had big issues using Soap services with Android and everything worked well... But now, I have to implement a new WebService, and what changes is that it's URL is in 'https', and the request must be authenticated by a Username and a Password...

When I test the service with a software such as SoapUI, everything works great :
I set 'Username', 'Password', and 'WSS-PasswordType' (password-text) into the request properties, and the WebService answer is OK.

By searching on other stackoverflow threads, I found a lot of possible solutions : Some are creating a **security header**, and add it to the Soap envelope, some others are directly encoding the Username + the Password into the **httpHeaders**, taken in parameter by HttpTransportSe...

Which one of these two solutions is appropriate ? I can't really tell...
As SoapUI is sending the following **Soap** header to the WebService I use; I think the best solution would be to work around the Soap security Header, and not with the HttpHeader, right ?

Header sent by SoapUI :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-15D8F1FA3D4EB11CFD144740958185128">
      <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
      <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">oiHJvIxwZ1/UsSRg+KL2aw==</wsse:Nonce>
      <wsu:Created>2015-11-13T10:13:01.851Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Header sent by my Android app :

```
  <v:Header>
<n0:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:n0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
  <n0:UsernameToken>
    <n0:Username>username</n0:Username>
    <n0:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</n0:Password>
    <n0:Nonce>oiHJvIxwZ1/UsSRg+KL2aw==</n0:Nonce>
    <n1:Created xmlns:n1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2015-11-12T16:01:01.004Z</n1:Created>
  </n0:UsernameToken>
</n0:Security>
```

So as I said, here are the two methods that I tried :
The Soap Header one.. Resulting a 400 Http error response

```
    Element headers[] = new Element[1];
headers[0]= new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Security");
headers[0].setAttribute(null, "soap:mustUnderstand", "1");

Element to = new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "UsernameToken");

Element action1 = new Element().createElement(null, "n0:Username");
action1.addChild(Node.TEXT, "username");
to.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,action1);

Element action2 = new Element().createElement(null, "n0:Password");
action2.setAttribute(null, "Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
action2.addChild(Node.TEXT, "password");
to.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,action2);

Element action3 = new Element().createElement(null, "n0:Nonce");
action3.setAttribute(null, "Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary");
action3.addChild(Node.TEXT, "PhWZD/H5OnnqW6wcavoNGg==");
to.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,action3);

Element action4 = new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "Created");
action4.addChild(Node.TEXT, "2015-11-12T16:01:01.004Z");
to.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,action4);

headers[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT, to);
```

And the HttpHeader one... With this one I am getting a 407 Http response (PROXY_AUTH)

```
httpHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
httpHeaders.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode("username:password".getBytes())));
transport.call(methodName, envelope, httpHeaders);
```

I think I have tried almost everything, so I will appreciate every suggests...
Thanks in advance